# Missing a rewrite flag? server 500 caused by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have an htaccess file on my root dir. I created a NEW htaccess file inside of callbacks/api and entered this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /callbacks/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr)$ ./endpoint.php?api_request=$1&api_response_type=$2
```

I am following the same rewrite rules that I have in my other htaccess (that work just fine). However in this instance I pass the following URL:

```
domain.com/callbacks/api/v1/test_rest.xml
```

Inside of my endpoint.php file I have:

```
<?
//just making sure the 500 is not due to php
//so lets just dump the GET's
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Am i missing a flag required at the end of my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /callbacks/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(json|xml|csv|txt|printr)$ ./endpoint.php?api_request=$1& api_response_type=$2   [L]
```

I did not test the rule, just added 2 lines to prevent loops.

Comment: Still a 500 error. error_log shows nothing. It is on a shared server so I can't tail -f the apache error_log to give any other ideas. Should I contact my host for a better idea as to what apache is saying?

Comment: Okay. ¿Why are you setting the Rewrite Base to `/callbacks/api` and where is the .htaccess file located, at root, at `/api`, where?

Comment: the `.htaccess` is in `www/callbacks/api`

Comment: ¿What about the RewriteBase?

Comment: I originally had the base set to `/` and thought maybe I needed to specify the path, I just never changed it back before I copied it into SO. There is no specific reason for it I guess?

Comment: I will test your rule and get back to you.

Comment: Please give an example of how should be the redirected URL. It's hard to guess that part. You want `domain.com/callbacks/api/v1/test_rest.xml` to be redirected. that's clear. But how? This is what you are getting now `http://www.domain.com/endpoint.php?api_request=callbacks/api/v1/test_rest&api_response_type=xml`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I apologize. The host answered my ticket and have "fixed" the issue. Nothing has changed from my original HTACCESS so I assume it may have been a server setting. Thank you for the help +1 for really trying to help. I replied to the ticket to see what exactly the issue was.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if you need any further help when you test it. Update your question if so.